# Does a British citizen need a transit visa in Basel?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, transit-visas, uk-citizens, switzerland

I am a British citizen flying from the UK to Germany, stopping in Basel in Switzerland for about 5 to 6 hours waiting for a connecting flight to Dresden. Do I need to obtain a visa?

Comment: What? No, you're the EU citizen and can enjoy the freedom of movement.

Comment: I assume the reason behind this question is the misconception that British citizens need a visa to enter Switzerland. However, Basel airport is not even in Switzerland, it's physically located in France and is jointly operated by France and Switzerland.

Comment: @Jonathan that must have been interesting before Switzerland joined the Schengen area.

Comment: @phoog There were two exits, one with Swiss border control and one with French (Schengen) border control.

Comment: @Jonathan Its border control is actually staffed by both Swiss and French officers working together. After baggage Claim, you can choose between an Exit for Switzerland and one France. Thus, if taking the bus to Zurich, which leaves from the French side, 50% of the time you'll be checked again by the Swiss (or in one exceptional case, strangely enough, by French *customs*) at the motorway checkpoint.

Comment: @Crazydre yes, i know that.  I'm thinking about those leaving the airport by plane.   Were there three sterile areas (Switzerland, Schengen, other)?

Comment: @phoog Departing passengers went through each border control, then the corridors merged into one sterile area.

Comment: @Crazydre So a flight from that airport to Germany was treated as an external flight?

Comment: @phoog Yes, those I remember are Lufthansa to Munich and easyjet to Berlin-Schönefeld, and some flight to Crete. WIZZ to Poland, however, left from an internal gate

Answer (score 6):

As long as the UK remains in the EU, you are also an EU citizen, so you cannot be required to have a visa to enter other EU countries.  Switzerland is not in the EU, but it is a member of the Schengen system and participates in the freedom-of-movement regime, so you also cannot be required to have a visa there.

After the UK leaves the EU, its citizens will probably continue to enjoy visa-free status in the Schengen area, like citizens of most other countries with strong economies, but if the exit negotiations go particularly poorly then they might be required to have visas.

Comment: For tourism and basic transit, yes; but I needed a visa to take up a private commission there.

Comment: ... before UK joined the EU, its citizens were not required to have a visa to visit "the continent".

Comment: @WeatherVane that has little bearing on the state after the UK leaves, of course. For one thing, the Schengen agreement did not exist when the UK joined the EU.  For UK nationals to be exempt from Schengen visa requirements after leaving they will have to be added to"Annex II," which is very likely but not entirely certain.  For example, if the UK decides to start requiring visas of nationals of some EU countries, the EU might refuse to add the UK to the annex.

Comment: @Edd on the other hand, the US requires visas of several EU countries' citizens, and plans to remove the US from Annex II are basically goingnowhere.

Comment: Switzerland is not in the EU but Basel airport is. It's located in France.

Comment: @WeatherVane also, that statement may not be strictly true.  For example, I am sure you are right that they did not need visas for the western parts of the continent, but I suspect that they did need them to get into more easterly places that now belong to the EU like Poland, Czechoslovakia, and Hungary.  I know from personal experience that US citizens needed a visa to enter Hungary by land in 1988, though the visa was available at the border.

Comment: @GayotFow Obviously before Switzerland became part of the freedom of movement. Otherwise EU citizens can only get residence Permits, which are old-style booklets like the old Italian ID card

Comment: @Crazydre 2010 time frame

Comment: @GayotFow What was the visa called? Are you absolutely sure you don't mean a residence Permit (again, a white booklet)? That's what I have, being that I live there

Answer (score 0):

You are still in the EU, and Switzerland is an EFTA state, so you never ever need a visa to go there under the current rules.

For the record, you'll clear Immigration at Basel and then fly to Dresden without any border control (unless the flight leaves from a non-Schengen gate, which happened to a bunch of flights to Germany and Greece in late May)